# Increase minimum user password length?

Tags: password

For security reason i would like to enforce users to set 10 character password length .

How can i modify this policy ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal :

```
sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

Add :

```
password [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512 **min=10**
```

As you can see min=xx will specify the x number of character should the password include .